# If charge is carried by ions, is there a limit to the amount of charge that salt water can conduct?

Tags: electricity

The reason salt water is so conductive is dissolved ions (e.g. $\mathrm{Cl^-}$ and $\mathrm{Na^+}$). If I put an anode and a cathode in water, will ions eventually build up and create an opposing voltage which would slow the current flow?

Does this make salt water is less a conductor, and more like a cell or a capacitor?